# How to update data grid bound to data table with MySQL data adapter

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I pull from my MySQL database, and fill it using a MySQLDataAdapter. MasterDataTable is my class level DT.

```
Dim SQLstring As String = "SELECT * FROM Inventory.Metadata"
Using cmdSel As New MySqlCommand(SQLstring, MySQLconn.conn)
   Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel)
   da.Fill(MasterDataTable)
End Using
```

Somebody updates the MySQL database, and I want to refresh the data again.

```
MasterDataTable.Clear() 
Dim SQLstring As String = "SELECT * FROM Inventory.Metadata"
Using cmdSel As New MySqlCommand(SQLstring, MySQLconn.conn)
   Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel)
   da.Fill(MasterDataTable)
End Using
```

The problem is, if the user has something selected, it will clear their selection.

Obviously this clears the datatable and re-fills it. Is there any way to accomplish the same task without `MasterDataTable.clear`?

Comment: First, `Update` is the means to send changes in the DataTable to the DB.  The function of refreshing - getting other changes into the DT - is performed via the `Fill` method.  From MSDN *Adds or refreshes rows in a specified range in the DataSet to match those in the data source using the DataTable name.* Dont clear the DataTable - the DA knows things...IMO, generally a local DataAdapter is a waste - they are very powerful and worth configuing and holding onto

Comment: @Plutonix If I don't clear the datatable, the data shows up twice, this is what I'm trying to avoid. Are you saying this is happening because I'm creating a new DA and filling the DT with it? Sorry, a little nooby with this whole MySQL thing lol.

Comment: There are probably two main options here. Firstly, you can remember what the user had selected and then reinstate that after the refresh. The second option is to populate a second `DataTable` and then merge that into your first rather than populating the first again. Of course, the second option can't help you if records can be physically deleted. You'd have to logically delete only.

Comment: On second thoughts, the second option may still be able to handle physical deletions but might take a bit more effort.

Comment: Step 1. Use an orm like entity framework.

Comment: Step 2. Read just records that have changed from the database.

Comment: Step 3. Depends on how you want your ui to work. If this is wpf bind selecteditem to a property in your vm. If that is one of the records changed then update that selecteditem property to the new object.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yea, what i'm trying to catch are deletions, lets say from another user. The datadapter,fill shows updates and additions, just not deletions (if another user did the deletion). I'm trying to figure out how I would handle them.

Comment: If you retrieve the current data into a separate `DataTable` then the lack of a record in that indicates that it was deleted, so you can remove it from the `DataTable` bound to the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used jmcilhinney's suggestion, created a separate table, compared the two, and deleted from main table if it didn't exist in the other.

Thanks :)